# Regarding generate and remove html elements dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project in that there is a requirement of dynamically generate html elements, one is date-picker and another one is time range, and it should generate dynamically whenever i click on add row for date-picker and for multiple time ranges. 
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Please show us, What you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                        <div id="date-selection">
                            <div class="row" id="date_count_0">
                                <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <input type="text" name="date[0]" value="" class="form-control datepicker"/> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info" id="add_date"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="timing-selection_0">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                <input type="text" name="dat[0][from]" value="" class="form-control time-picker" /> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                <input type="text" name="dat[0][to]" value="" class="form-control time-picker" /> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info add_timings" id="add_timings_0" data-id="0" onclick="add_timings(this)">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                </a> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var date_count = 1;
            var time_count = 1;
            function add_timings(attr){
                var thisid = $(attr).data("id");
                var inner_timings = "<div id='delete_timing_" + time_count + "'><div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-12'>" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-5'>" +
                        "<input type='text' name='dat[" + thisid + "][from]' value='' class='form-control time-picker' /> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-5'>" +
                        "<input type='text' name='dat[" + thisid + "][to]' value='' class='form-control time-picker' /> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: right;'>" +
                        "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info add_timings' id='add_timings_" + time_count + "' onclick='deletetimings(" + time_count + ")'>" +
                        "<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>" +
                        "</a> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>";
                $(".timing-selection_" + thisid).append(inner_timings);
                $('.time-picker').timepicker({
                    template: false,
                    showInputs: false,
                    minuteStep: 5
                });
                time_count++;
            }
            $("#add_date").on("click", function (row, index) {
                var texttoappend = "<div id='delete_row_" + date_count + "'>" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-11'>" +
                        "<input type='text' name='date[" + date_count + "]' value='' class='form-control datepicker' /> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-1' style='text-align: right;'>" +
                        "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info' onclick='delete_date(" + date_count + ");'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" +
                        "<div class='timing-selection_" + date_count + "'>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-12'>" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-5'>" +
                        "<input type='text' name='date[" + date_count + "][from]' value='' class='form-control time-picker' /> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-5'>" +
                        "<input type='text' name='date[" + date_count + "][to]' value='' class='form-control time-picker' /> " +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='col-md-2' style='text-align: right;'>" +
                        "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info add_timings' id='add_timings_"+date_count+"' data-id='"+date_count+"' onclick='add_timings(this)'>"+
                            "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>"+
                        "</a>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>";
                "</div>";
                $("#date-selection").append(texttoappend + "<br />");
                date_count++;
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                });
                $('.time-picker').timepicker({
                    template: false,
                    showInputs: false,
                    minuteStep: 5
                });
            });
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            });
            $('.time-picker').timepicker({
                template: false,
                showInputs: false,
                minuteStep: 5
            });
            function delete_date(datecount) {
                $("#delete_row_" + datecount).remove();
            }
            function deletetimings(datecount) {
                $("#delete_timing_" + datecount).remove();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How this is related to question asked?

Comment: Hi g.v.v.phani Guduri, Thanks for your answer, that's what i needed. thank you.